# cp .* /home/name erased all files in /home/name

Tags: data-recovery, mv, cp

A while ago, I got a new ssd for my laptop, so I dd'd everything onto the new drive, and used it for a while without issue. I decided to put the old drive back into my laptop, and put newer ssd into a nvme-USB connector. I wanted to copy my personal files over, but I wasn't certain everything would go according to plan, so I moved everything in /home/name into /home/name/oldstuff, a new folder, so I could go back. I started with mv instead of cp by brain-mistake:

```
cd /media/drive/home/name
mv * /home/name
```

but that missed all files starting with "." so I did

`cp .* /home/name`

I started getting errors relating to permissions of things in the relative path ./../othername, and I assumed the safest thing to do was hit CTRL+C, and then did

`cp .[a-z]* /home/name`

when that completed, everything that had been in /home/name was gone (including the poorly located backup I made) some of which was fairly important. Is there a way for me to get it back?

Comment: it's ext4 data with a fat32 EFI partition. It was a bootable linux install, now just moved outside the laptop.

Comment: good! In that case you should be able to copy it back. FYI: if you nuke a home and log in all system files are recreated so all you need to worry about is your personal data en maybe a configuration here and there.

Comment: the files were missing in /home/name, and I used mv from the external drive so they are gone there as well. And I just turned my laptop on for the 4th time and everything is back! (the previous 3 times didn't restore anything). The only things different this time are, 1. I used shutdown -0 instead of reboot, and 2.I unplugged the external drive so I could tell you the file system type without booting up my laptop. Any idea what on Earth could have happened?

Answer (score 1):

Using glob characters like `*` **should be done very carefully** and you should know how they are expanded by your shell and passed to your command as arguments.

- `*` will expand to include files and directories under **current directory**.
- `.*` will expand to include **current directory** `.` and the **directory one level up** `..`.
- `.[a-z]*` will expand to include **hidden files/directories in current directory with first lower case letter in their names**.

To see, for example, how `.*` will be expanded on your system run `set -x` then run:

```
ls .*
```

or alternatively use `echo` to print the expanded list like so:

```
echo .*
```

or use `readlink -f` to get the full path of the expanded list like so:

```
readlink -f .*
```